# Why can't I include an <img> tag in my user profile's "About Me" section?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, profile-page

This is my `"About Me"` code i have now `Flying with <b>WCF</b> and <b>Jquery</b>....`

But when I change this to:

```
Flying with <b>WCF</b> and <b>Jquery</b>.... 

<img src="http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/8413/copyofdevelopersareborn.jpg"
alt="Great Pic" width="210" height="263" />
```

It doesn't seem to take my `<img>` tag... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Be mindful of the order of your attributes as well as the self-closing end slash `/` (since the sites are HTML 4)

So your image needs to be coded up as:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" width="125" height="225" alt="uighur">
```

Variations include:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" width="125" height="225" alt="yo ho" > 

<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" width="125" height="225"> 

<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="Ho-hum image"> 

<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
```

Comment: but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed? why cant i include width and height?

Comment: @Pandiya - Could it be the order order of the tags that's the problem?

Comment: @Chris Ok i ll try it out...

Comment: Yeah, I have been proudly displaying an image on my profile for a while, I remember the width and height attributes working for me, I don't know what's going wrong for you.

Comment: @Sam152 and @Chris It was the order that was the prob....